# Is there a word for an idea similar to negative evidence?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

My question will best be summed up by this phenomenon.

A few thousand years ago, all Jews believed that the tablets containing the ten commandments were square, there was no debate regarding their shape, and therefore, no one ever wrote what their shape was. They described their size, and how they fit in a square box perfectly, but they never bothered to explicitly mention whether the tablets were round or square.

So I'm looking for a word or a phrase that describes the phenomenon of something being so obvious that no one bothers to write it down.

Comment: But they have arc-ed tops in all of the movies... what do you mean they're square? ;)

Comment: I don't follow your example: " few thousand years ago, all Jews believed that the tablets containing the ten commandments were square...no one ever wrote what their shape was...they never bothered to explicitly mention whether the tablets were round or square."  So how do you know *what* they believed?

Comment: Because of their writings, drawings, paintings, etc. i'm giving a speech tonight with my collected evidence.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like *[conventional wisdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_wisdom)*

> the body of ideas or explanations generally accepted as true by the public or by experts in a field. Such ideas or explanations, though widely held, are unexamined.

*Wikipedia*

The term *[given](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/given)* (as a noun) can also apply

> an assumed fact

*Collins*

Comment: Ah, i added some edits, i had forgotten to include a crucial part

Comment: btw you are describing a **phenomenon**, not _this phenomena_ (sic)

Comment: `+1` for *a given*. That should be the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

The term I would use would be  ***default position***, borrowed from wordprocessing, though the only example I have is from a Wordpress page.

> The term “default position” refers to a belief (or lack of belief)
>   that is preferable prior to debate or before any evidence is
>   considered.

Answer (score 1):

Historians and the like call this [**tacit** (or **implicit**) **knowledge**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_knowledge) - things that were considered so obvious no-one ever bothered to write them down, but which may not be at all obvious centuries or millennia later.